# Why is there no CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to compile nvidia Maxine with cmake but am getting this error

````
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!```
````

Comment: Try sharing the `CMakeLists.txt`. Normally, you're just missing one of the listed resources.

Comment: here is the `CMakeLists.txt` file https://pastebin.com/312TiGgx

Comment: Do you have any C++ compiler _installed_? Please post _all_ the messages from cmake configuration.

Comment: these are all the config messages there are
`Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19041.
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "{path}".
See also "{path}".`
and the output log
`The system is: Windows - 10.0.19041 - AMD64`

Comment: oh and then there is the error log file, here https://pastebin.com/7LBj8nS9

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=fatal+error+LNK1181%3A+cannot+open+input+file+%27kernel32.lib%27 . Please _edit_ your question and post new information there, rather then in comments.

Comment: What are you using to install with `cmake`? I made the assumption that you were using Bash, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It looks like it's running in an IDE, but I'm not sure. If it is running in an IDE, you are going to have to configure it and install older versions of Visual Studio. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio toolchain, clang, mingw, or something else? The way of fixing this depends on what compiler you want to use.

Comment: @icebp that was my question too lol